# Using a single ManyToMany relation table instead of ManyToMany & ForeignKey field on multiple models?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a Django application that handles data analysis workflows, with database models that look something like this:

```
class Workflow(models.Model):
    execution_id = models.UUIDField()

class WorkflowItem(models.Model):
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow)
    type = models.CharField(choices=["input", "output"])
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)

class File(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField()

class FileMetadata(models.Model):
    metadata = models.JSONField()
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

A given `Workflow` will have many `WorkflowItem`'s, which correspond to `File`'s which can be used by `WorkflowItem`'s across many `Workflow`'s. Each `File` can have many associated `FileMetadata`'s, of which the entry with the max `version` value is typically used for a given operation.

As the application has been growing, its getting tedious to build out all the different combinations of logic needed to find the entries in one table based on a given entry in another table just by using each tables' Foreign Key interface (`Workflow` <-> `WorkflowItem` <-> `File` <-> `FileMetadata`).

I am considering just building a table that holds all the foreign keys for every relationship in a single place. Something like this:

```
class WorkflowFile(models.Model):
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow)
    workflow_item = models.ForeignKey(WorkflowItem)
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    file_metadata = models.ForeignKey(FileMetadata)
```

However, I am not sure if this is a good idea or not. Its not clear to me if implementing a table like this is advantageous compared to just following all the foreign key relationships individually per-table. Its also not clear to me how I should set up such a table through Django, and if the new requirement for manually entering values into this table all the time would outweigh the reduced need for unique query logic every time I want to query these relationships. My end-goal is to provide a simpler, more consistent way to get all of the items in the relationship based on any of the other items in the relationship.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286930/django-manytomanyfield-on-multiple-attributes-of-multiple-class) seems similar in premise, but I am not clear that the problem or proposed solution is relevant to what I am looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will actually answer your question but if you want to go the way with multiple FK's then you may consider using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table in combination with [m2m changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) to add proper FK's to this model after adding M2M records to `WorkflowItem`.

It'll be something like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

class WorkflowItem(models.Model):
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow)
    type = models.CharField(choices=["input", "output"])
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, through=IntermediateTable)

class IntermediateTable(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(File, related_name='file')
    workflow_item = models.ForeignKey(WorkflowItem, related_name='worflowitem')
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow, null=True)
    file_metadata = models.ForeignKey(FileMetadata)

def workflow_item_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.workflow = sender.workflow_item.workflow
    ...
    sender.save()

m2m_changed.connect(workflow_item_changed, sender=WorkflowItem.files.through)
```